# Recursively remove n-th element of all sub-lists (with restrictions) in Common Lisp

Tags: list, common-lisp

I'm a couple of weeks in my study of Lisp (mostly recursion). So far, I've mostly been dealing with simple enough functions that test the basic knowledge of recursion (car, cdr, cond, remove, nth etc.). I stumbled upon a simple problem that I just can't get right. The problem goes:

> Write a function remove-nth that takes two arguments:

```
(defun remove-nth (n l)

)
```

> Where n is a non-negative integer and list is a list/atom/null. The function removes the n-th element (one-based indexing) of the original list and any-level sub-lists that it contains. The operation can be either destructive or non-destructive.

So, for example:

```
(remove-nth 3 '((1 2 3 4) ((1 3 5) 3 1) (1 2 2 1))) --> ((1 2 4) ((1 3) 3))
```

What I've tried:

```
(defun remove-nth (n L)
   (cond
       ((null L) nil)
       ((listp L)
            (cons (remove-nth n (car (r n L))) (remove-nth n (cdr (r n L)))))
       (t L)      
   )
)

(defun r (n L)   
    (remove (nth (- n 1) L) L)
)
```

This code doesn't work because it sometimes removes an element twice from the **same** list, e.g. calling:

```
(remove-nth 2 '((1 2 3 4) ((1 3 5) 3 1) (1 2 2 1)))
```

ought to output

```
((1 3 4) (1 2 1))
```

but in my case, it outputs:

```
((1 3) (1 1))
```

i.e. the sub-list (1 2 2 1) has **two** elements removed instead of just one. I reckon there is an oversight in the way I'm trying to handle the recursive calls, but I've tried many different approaches and I can't get any to work. So, I've turned to you guys for help.

I am not asking for the code per se, but rather an explanation, or a hint on how to better my approach.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you wanted to write `(remove-nth 2 '((1 2 3 4) ((1 3 5) 3 1) (1 2 2 1))) ` in the listing after the implementation ;) I can't edit this myself, since an edit must be at least 6 chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code, it should work as you wanted:

```
(defun remove-nth (n L)
   (cond
       ((null L) nil)
       ((listp L)
        (map 'list (lambda (l) (remove-nth n l)) (r n L)))
       (t L)))

(defun r (n L)                                     
   (if (or (= n 1) (null L)) 
      (cdr L) 
      (cons (car L) (r (1- n) (cdr L)))))
```

There are 2 problems with your approach:

1. In function `r` you're not removing the nth element - you're removing *every element that's equal* to the nth element of the list. Because of that the list `'(1 2 2 1)` is transformed to `'(1 1)` - the 2nd element is `2`, so every `2` is removed.
2. In function `remove-nth` you're recursing down into the first element and right into the tail of the list - because of the second recursion you're removing more elements that you should. That's apparent in the case of the list `'(1 2 3 4)`. It becomes `'(1 3 4)` after the call to `r`, then you decompose it into `car` (equal to `1`) and `cdr` (equal to `'(3 4)`). After recursing into the second one, you once again remove the 2nd element and you get `'(3)`. This, after `cons`, gives you the list `'(1 3)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It cleared a lot of my misunderstandings (especially in the case of 'remove'). Please bear in mind that I'm relatively new to LISP, so, could you tell me what exactly does the line: (map 'list (lambda (l) (remove-nth n l)) (r n L))) do? Thanks!

Comment: Of course! `map` is a function that has 3 parameters:
The first describes the type of its result (in this case it's `'list`);
The second one is a function with one parameter (in this case I've created a lambda to wrap the call to `remove-nth`);
The third one is a collection.

The `map` function then goes and applies the function (2nd param) to every element of the collection (3rd param) and puts all the results into a collection of the proper type (1st param).

Look [here](http://jtra.cz/stuff/lisp/sclr/map.html) for examples.

Comment: I should add that `map` has 3 parameters in this case - in the link you can see examples of different arities. The rule is that you need to supply as much collections as your function (2nd param) has parameters itself.